# Angular2 Systemjs application control flow

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, systemjs

I started learning Angular2 and finding it difficult to find the flow of application.

systemjs.config.js

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'dist',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
     System.import('app').catch(function(err){ alert(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>APP WORKS</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]
When I run application, I see output as "Hello Angular" which is correct and it is working properly.

My question is how the `System.import('app')` worked? I don't have any folder or file name app in any directory.

Also, there is entry in `systemjs.config.js` as `"app: { main: './main.js',"`
what exactly is relation between declaration in `systemjs.config.js` and `System.import('app')`. how control of application flows?

If I change `System.import('app')` to `System.import('abc')` then I got error.

Answer (score 0):

Good Question ;)

```
<script>
     System.import('app').catch(function(err){ alert(err); });
</script>
```

here in this lines of code `system.import` loads a main file for the app,
actually systemJs is a module loader, which loads the module for your app.

`systemjs.config.js` is  normal javascript file where we write a bunch of code for simplicity instead in a single file. where we tell angular to load main file first.
like here

`"app: { main: './main.js',....`

> If I change System.import('app') to System.import('abc') then I got error.

Yes, because here app is a file variable which binds to the main.js file where we bootstraped the whole app to load, otherwise abc is nothing so it throw error.

Hope it clear some points.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. so you mean to say "app" is inbuilt variable which is bind to "main.js" (which is loaded by systemjs.config.js)? can you please help me on documentation link or any article where I can read more on this "app" variable

Comment: no , not at all you can assume abc also instead of app, but thing is you must have to use same variable in the sysem.config.js and index.html file

Comment: actually according to Update, its tough to find configuration of system.config.js file, you can check the official site for Upation.

Comment: "you must have to use same variable in the system.config.js and index.html file" - which variable in system.config.js should i write "abc", so that it will work?

Answer (score 0):

Extracted from the SystemJS documentation at https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#packages:

"Packages provide a convenience for setting meta and map configuration that is specific to a common path."

Given your current configuration, System.import('app') instructs SystemJS to load './main.js', the entry point specified in the 'app' package under the attribute 'main'.

```
packages: {
  app: {
    main: './main.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  rxjs: {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
}
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly, when index.html file is loaded, it encounters "<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>" through which systemjs.config.js loads and it doesn't do anything(or it load a main.js file and make it available for use). now when it encounters  System.import('app'), it checks the mapping of "app { main: './main.js'" of  systemjs.config.js and load main.js file? Please verify my understanding.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The systemjs.config.js file configures SystemJs on load. SystemJs then knows how to resolve 'app' when System.import('app') is called.

Comment: No problem, @Rahul. Could you please choose and/or upvote an answer?

Comment: I want to upvote and I did as well but due to less reputation It is not allowing me. (I think minimum 15 reputation is required)